# EASA Medical Centre Canada

Tags: medical

I am looking to go to Europe for flight school, I need to get a EASA Class 1, are there any EASA approved medical center's in Canada?

Comment: There are CAMEs in Canada who are licensed to do FAA medicals, but I've never heard of one that does EASA ones.

Comment: That's an answer I'd upvote @DJClayworth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any EASA medical examiners in Canada. However a class 1 medical can be issued the same day of the exam, so you could book a medical in Europe the day before you are due to start flight training. If you are starting from scratch a class 2 might be sufficient to get you through the initial training. It would probably be a good idea to have a Canadian ME look you over first - they can tell you if there is anything wrong with you that might cause you to fail the EASA class 1, even if they can't give you the EASA certificate. That way you wouldn't waste money on flying to Europe and booking flight training only to fail the medical.